# How to get data out of stdclass object?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, stdclass

I am using `$this->db->get_where()` to get data from database in codeigniter.
Its returning following which I got using `print_r()`

Its looks like array of `stdClass object`. Anyone who how to access values inside this array.

```
Array ( [0] =>    
    stdClass Object ( 
    [id] => 1 
    [password321] => qwerty
    [email123] => example@gmail.com 
    [username123] => xyz
    ) 
)
```

Comment: `$array[0]->id` should echo 1

Comment: @Labeeb. Have provided with a solution for the request that you have asked the question. Have a try and share thoughts.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It shows an array of objects.  There is only one object in it.

If:

```
$var =  $this->db->get_where();
```

Then:

```
echo $var[0]->id;
```

Answer (score 6):

Access it like any other object.

```
echo $array[0]->id //1
echo $array[0]->username123 //xyz
```

And so on. If you have multiple objects inside the array, run it through a `for loop` to iterate the array.

For example:

```
for ($i=0;$i<sizeof($array);$i++) {
    echo $array[$i]->[object property];
}
```